# How to listen to "data-dropdown-toggle" property Dropdown's flowbite plugin in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-ui, flowbite

Because when a link is clicked inside the Dropdown itself the link takes you to the other place but the Dropdown remains opened, and it should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't available yet.

You can read more about it here:
https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/discussions/184#discussioncomment-5292164